# Ergodic theory question about the support of a measure.

Tags: metric-spaces, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I am trying to work through some problems from  " Ergodic theory with view towards number theory" but I am finding it a tad more difficult than expected. In particular, I have the following question:

> For $X$ a compact metric space, $T:X\to X$ continuous and $\mu$ a $T$-invariant ergodic probability measure defined on the Borel sets of $X$. Prove that for $\mu$ almost every $x\in X$ and $y\in \operatorname{Supp}(\mu)$ there exists a sequence $n_k\nearrow\infty$ such that $T^{n_k}(x)\to y$. Recall
>   $$\operatorname{Supp}(\mu)=X-\bigcup U$$
>   where $U\subset X$ is open and has null measure.

This problem screams the Poincaré Recurrence Theorem to me, but I am not sure where to use it. I could really use some guidance for this problem.

NOTE: This is not homework for a class, I just really want to learn ergodic theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It is enough to prove that for each $y\in\operatorname{Supp}\mu$, we have 
   $$\mu\{x\in X\mid\exists n_k\uparrow +\infty, T^{n_k}x\to y\}=1.$$
   Indeed, assume we have done that. The support of $\mu$ is a closed set in a separable metric space, hence it is separable. Let $\{y_j,j\in\Bbb N\}$ be a countable dense subset. As a countable union of negligible sets is negligible, we have 
   $$\mu\left\{x\in X\mid\forall j\in\Bbb N,\exists n_k\uparrow +\infty, T^{n_k}x\to y_j\right\}=1.$$
   Let $y\in \operatorname{Supp}(\mu)$. Then for each $i$, consider $y_{j_i}$ for which $d(y,y_{j_i})<i^{-1}$, and construct $(n_i)$ by induction, taking $d(y_{j_i},T^{n_i}x)<i^{-1}$.
2. Fix now $y\in\operatorname{Supp}\mu$, and call $C:=\left\{x\in X\mid\exists n_k\uparrow +\infty, T^{n_k}x\to y\right\}$. We can check that $C$ is almost invariant, in sense that $\mu(C\Delta T^{-1}C)=0$. As $T$ is ergodic, the measure of $C$ is either $0$ or $1$.
3. As $y$ is in the support of $\mu$, for each $l$, $\mu\left(B\left(y,l^{-1}\right)\right)$ is positive. By [Poincaré recurrence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_recurrence_theorem#Formal_statement_of_the_theorem),  $\mu\left( \left\{x\in B\left(y,l^{-1}\right) \mid T^nx\in  B\left(y,l^{-1}\right)\mbox{ for infinitely many }n\mbox{'s}   \right\}  \right)$ is positive hence, by ergodicity, its value is $1$. Therefore, the measure of $C$ is $1$.

Comment: 2.What is the set $Y$ that you use in your proof?
3. Does $C$ being that union over $l$ lead to some contradiction that I am not seeing?
4. Maybe the most important question I have, what advice do you have so that I can find my way to a similar proof?

Comment: 3. It's a contradiction of Poincaré recurrence theorem. indeed, we would have that each element $\{x,d(y,O(x))>l^{-1}\}=0$ for all $l$. But $B(y,l^{-1})$ contains a set of positive measure for which each point returns infinitely often. 4. First, try to answer the problem in a simple case, for example $X$ is the unit interval or the torus, then try to see why this can be extended, or which properties allow a generalization.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo I know this is an old question, but would you mind explaining step 3? I'm not seeing the identity $C=\bigcup_{l\ge 1} \{x: d(y,O(x))>l^{-1})$. If $x$ is in $C$, then there is a sequence $n_k$ with $T^{n_k}x\to y$, and thus $d(y,O(x))=0$.

Comment: @Reveillark This identity does not hold. I have edited.

Comment: I was going to ask another question, but your last edit clarified things. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Realize that it is enough to prove the following proposition:

(P1) For $\mu$ almost every $x \in X$, when you pick any neighborhood $U$ around any point in the support, we have that $x$ visits $U$ infinitely many times (i.e., $T^{i} x \in U$ for infinitely many $i \ge 0$).

This kind of realization where the strictly increasing sequence $(n_k)_k$ is dealt away from the beginning is a standard trick when dealing with things like omega limits..

Let's prove P1. Suppose $y$ is some arbitrary point in the support and $U$ is some neighborhood of $y$. Consider the following proposition about $U$:

(P($U$)) For $\mu$ almost every $x \in X$, $x$ visits $U$ infinitely many times.

The proposition P($U$) is true because $U$ has positive measure and $\mu$ is ergodic. (Use the ergodic theorem. If you want to avoid using the ergodic theorem at this point, use the fact that $x$ must visit $U$ at least once and the fact that visiting $U$ once is enough to guarantee infinitely many visits (this is Poincare recurrence theorem))

Since $y$ and $U$ were arbitrary, can we conclude that P1 is true? We just need to tackle the problem that there could be more than countably many choices for $y$ and $U$. But notice that the proposition P($U$) makes no reference to $y$, so uncountably many possibilities for $y$ is not a problem. We only need to deal with uncountably many possibilities for $U$.

Since $X$ is second countable, we have a countable collection $\mathcal U_{\mu}$ such that each element in the collection is a neighborhood of some point in the support and that for each $y$ in the support and each neighborhood $U$ of $y$, there is $U' \in \mathcal U_{\mu}$ such that $y \in U' \subset U$.

To prove P1, it is enough to prove P2:

(P2) For $\mu$ almost every $x \in X$, for every $U \in \mathcal U_{\mu}$, $x$ visits $U$ infinitely many times.

But since $\mathcal U_{\mu}$ is countable, P2 is equivalent to P3:

(P3) For every $U \in \mathcal U_{\mu}$, for $\mu$ almost every $x \in X$, $x$ visits $U$ infinitely many times.

But P3 is something that we already proved.